# Как в компонент Angular прокинуть класс как параметр?

Tags: angular

Как сделать, что б можно было класс передать как параметр во внутрь компонента?
Например так

```
<app-my-component class-parameter="'my-class'"></app-my-component>
```

css:

```
.my-class {
   color: red; //.....
}
```

Но не записывать это в компоненте, а непосредственно передавая как параметр.

Comment: @InDevX , я написал параметр @Input() imageClass: string = '';
А как мне в родительском компоненте прокинуть?
как я понял потом нужно через renderer2 добавить или как это сделать?

Comment: @InDevX
В родительском компоненте хочу передать дочернему, что б то что он отрисует - было с определёнными стилями. В дочернем не хочу всё это прописывать, а что б было динамически. Пример - в родительском говорю - вот этот класс примени в дочернем.

Comment: "В дочернем не хочу всё это прописывать" Всё это = стили? Если да то [вот](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) или просто в корневом файле прописать их

Comment: @InDevX спасибо, да, использую иногда ng-deep, заработало. Хоть он уже как сто лет помечен как deprecated, но другого решения пока не видел. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, главное `Use ::ng-deep only with emulated view encapsulation.`, а другое решение я написал - киньте стили в глобальный файл стилей, styles.css

Comment: Можно создать параметризированную директиву, которая будет создавать класс из параметра. В  дочернем компоненте через @Input отлавливать этот параметр и проставлять элементу директиву с параметром.

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи правильно не через `@Input()`, а через `constructor(@Attribute('imageClass') public class: string = 'my-class') { }`.
Так как input отрабатывает на каждом цикле перерисовки, в отличье от инициализации в конструкторе.